# CFWheels - Dynamically Add Pages, Make URL Friendly

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels

I'm planning on creating a CMS for a website in CFWheels.
The concept is that an admin user would log in and be able to add/edit/delete pages to the website. I'm sure others are doing this so just wanted some feedback on what methods you are using to do this.

For example, if we want to add a "promotions" page, we would just fill out the create  page form with the name as "promotions" or some SEO friendly URL and we'll be able to see it by going to http://www.mysite.com/promotions or something like that.

Of course this would mean that the physical file "promotions" doesn't exist but I need it to display when users hit the mentioned URL. CFWheels uses the Model View Controller so it already has some redirects for that which make things a bit more difficult.

It would probably be best to have a draft system or revision system where we can preview the page before it actually goes "live".
How are you guys doing this?
I was also thinking it might be great if they can create pages and edit them inline right on the page as well. I took a look at CKEditor and looks like it's pretty good so I'll be playing around with that. If any of you have any examples or resources on this that would be great.

Again, I need a working concept in CFWheels.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be useful if a) You ask one question at time and b) tell us about what you have already tried.

Comment: Stop. Pick from Mura or FarCry or ContentBox or SplashCMS or [lots of others](http://www.carehart.org/cf411/#cms) - they have ***already solved*** these same problems, (including all the things that you haven't thought of yet).

Answer (score 2):

It has already been done.

[See SplashCMS listed on the CFWheels site](http://cfwheels.org/sites/listing/23)

And of course the [SplashCMS web site itself](http://splashcms.com/)

It is open source so I would recommend downloading that and investigating the code to see what they are doing. Or, better yet, don't reinvent the wheel and just use it. It is open source so you can always make changes/enhancements.

Here is another one - [EZPlug](https://code.google.com/p/ezplug/)

Not sure why you are stuck on CFWheels. If you are just looking for a ColdFusion CMS built using a framework MURA seems to be gaining ground - [GetMura.com](http://www.getmura.com/) (also open source)

*Added from Peter's comment* - [Charlie Arehart has a fairly extensive list of ColdFusion CMS's on his site](http://www.carehart.org/cf411/#cms).